# How can I toggle a class using v-bind to just this item in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a bottom navigation bar for my app. This navigation contains 4 icons, each when clicked, changes the view displayed. I want the icon which is selected to change from white to red. I figured a simple way to do this would be to toggle the class of `.active` when an icon in the navigation is selected. I currently have written some code that toggles the class of active. However, this toggles all of the list items and I need it to just change 'this' item and not the others. Plus the first list item should be set as active by defauly. Is there a way to do this?

My navigation component is as follows;

```
<li v-on:click="active = !active" v-bind:class="{active: active}">
    <router-link to="/pageOne">
        <i>Icon 1</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
<li v-on:click="active = !active" v-bind:class="{active: active}">
    <router-link to="/pageTwo">
        <i>Icon 2</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
<li v-on:click="active = !active" v-bind:class="{active: active}">
    <router-link to="/pageThree">
        <i>Icon 3</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
<li v-on:click="active = !active" v-bind:class="{active: active}">
    <router-link to="/pageFour">
        <i>Icon 4</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
```

Then the script below this is;

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "PrimaryAppNav",
  data() {
    return {
      active: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another solution aside from adding a `click` event handler to handle the `active` class toggling.

You could define a method under your `PrimaryAppNav` that will check the current active route path and returns a boolean value.

This way you don't have to store the currently toggled route under your component state as what you are currently doing right now with the `active` property.

```
<li v-bind:class="{ active: isActivePath('/pageOne') }">
    <router-link to="/pageOne">
        <i>Icon 1</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
<li v-bind:class="{ active: isActivePath('/pageTwo') }">
    <router-link to="/pageTwo">
        <i>Icon 2</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
<li v-bind:class="{ active: isActivePath('/pageThree') }">
    <router-link to="/pageThree">
        <i>Icon 3</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
<li v-bind:class="{ active: isActivePath('/pageFour') }">
    <router-link to="/pageFour">
        <i>Icon 4</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
```

And under your `PrimaryAppNav` `methods` property:

```
isActivePath(path) {
  return this.$route.path === path;
}
```

Comment: This is amazing @anaLiza. Thank you so much. I understand the logic now and the applied code works perfectly. Much appriciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
<template>
<li @click="toggleActive('pageOne')" :class="{active: active === 'pageOne'}">
    <router-link to="/pageOne">
        <i>Icon 1</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
<li @click="toggleActive('pageTwo')" :class="{active: active === 'pageTwo'}">
    <router-link to="/pageOne">
        <i>Icon 2</i>
    </router-link>
</li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      active: 'pageOne'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive(page) {
      this.active = page
    }
  }
}
</script>
```